# Javascript treats variable as string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following state change operation:

```
const handleQuantity=(e)=>{
        const targetedProductId=e.target.id
        // console.log(targetedProductId)
        const targetedProductQuantity=e.target.value
       setOrderProductQuantity({
        ...orderProductQuantity,
        targetedProductId:targetedProductQuantity
        })
    }
```

and my state is this :

```
const [orderProductQuantity,setOrderProductQuantity]=React.useState({})
```

The

```
console.log(targetedProductId)
```

shows the correct value

It **always** turns out that orderProductQuantity is updated with something like this:
`{"targetedProductId":e.target.value}` instead of `{e.target.id:e.target.value}`. Could you please explain why this happens, how could I fix it ? Thank you !

P.S. Tried with string literals, also doesn't work

Comment: I guess you need a dynamic key name `[targetedProductId]: targetedProductQuantity`.

Comment: Property keys are always literal in object literals, unless you enclose them in `[...]`.

Comment: @Andy  Indeed , thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not attributing the id value as the signatures of the parameter.

The correct way of doing so would be:

```js
const handleQuantity = (e) => {
    const targetedProductId = e.target.id;
    const targetedProductQuantity = e.target.value;

    setOrderProductQuantity({
        ...orderProductQuantity,
        [targetedProductId]: targetedProductQuantity
    });
}
```

With the square brackets you're telling javascript that you want to map the **value** in *targetedProductId*, instead of actually writing **targetedProductId**